# Bash string using string comparison operator working the wrong way - opposite to expected result

Tags: bash, if-statement, quotes

This is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ '$1' == 'movie' ]]
then
 echo 'true'
else
 echo 'false'
fi
```

But if I run it like this:

```
./bash.sh movie
```

It keep saying false.

Same if I write the code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ '$1' = 'movie' ]
then
 echo 'true'
else
 echo 'false'
fi
```

But if I do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ '$1' != 'movie' ]
then
 echo 'true'
else
 echo 'false'
fi
```

It says True!!!!

Help me.

Comment: variables does not expand within single quotes. So a literal `$1` will not match anything except for itself... Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)